# Не работает кнопка вверх

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите разобраться, есть [сайт](https://mymeizu.ru/mix/), на нем не работает кнопка вверх. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Толи в cкриптах, то ли где ошибка. Помогите разобраться. Как сделать чтобы работало.

Comment: допишите `$('html, body')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найдите скрипт:

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 500);
```

Замените на:

```
$('body, html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 500);
```